# Exclusion Script with Salesforce Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, exclusion-script

I'm using the folowing Exclusion script `ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("DE_TEST_FORCE10_FR", "CLI_AdresseEmail", emailaddr))> 0` during a one shot email and it works very well, the issue is when I move the standard Data Extension to a Salesforce Data Extension Folder and then retry the Use Case, the exclusion doesn't work any more.

Why does it no longer work? How can I fix it?

Comment: Is this a child business unit?  If so, you'll have to amend the DE name with `ENT.DE_TEST_FORCE10_FR`.  When you move it to a SF DE folder, it changes the directory listing and ampscript needs to know when to look outside the MC directory.

Comment: No, I have only one BU in my Account  (ENT 1.0)

Comment: Did you attempt the use of ENT. ?

Comment: I did try the ENT. unfortunalty, it's still ignoring the exclusion script.

Comment: FYI, SFMC support told that exclusion script doesn't works with Salesforce Data Extension. I had to use Standard Salesforce Data Extension.